# FloatinActionButton: the following classes could not be instantiated

Tags: java, android, floating-action-button

At first everything was fine, then came the error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

There also is an error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`: No drawer view found with `gravity` LEFT

dependencies:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you need the support v4 library as a dependency in your grade file but you have only the v7.

So you can add this to your dependencies (last line):

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
}
```